# Microsoft Graph, user companyname not writable?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am not able to write the property `companyName` to `users` via Microsoft Graph (only read).

I notice that the property is not listed in the [property documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/user), only in the JSON representation:

Is this intended behavior or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

<s>The documentation is incorrect here. It should note that `companyName` is currently a read-only property.</s>

Thank you for pointing this out, I will make sure the documentation gets updated accordingly.

As noted below by @Ari, [`companyName` is now writable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog?view=graph-rest-1.0#february-2019-1) via Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Thank you, do you know if this will be a writable property in the near future?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I've added a request to the UserVoice but I can't provide an ETA on when this will be changed.

Comment: As of February 2019 this property is now writable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog?view=graph-rest-1.0#february-2019-1